# Node.js For-Loop Callback Multiple Requests

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, callback

I have written code that works with Bookeo's API to be able to POST bookings for different tours. However, prior to POSTing I need to retrieve the eventId (generated by every tour) as a way to check for available slots for that booking. Thus for every booking I want to POST, I need to GET beforehand and use that variable in my POST. After researching I've found that I needed to make callbacks, and everyone is recommending async/await/promise but it somehow can't get through to my head. I don't even know how I managed to figure out callbacks.

My code is having an issue going past 5 bookings, and I believe it has something to do with my for loop where I loop the rows of a spreadsheet, that has pre-entered data to make the bookings (potentially interfering with the callback function or closure?)

I am trying to figure out how to change my code into one I could use the async module with. I tried whilst, but there is much going on with my code that I'm not even sure what's the best async solution for me. Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much for your time.

```
function sheetToBookeo(auth) {
    var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: auth,
        spreadsheetId: 'SPREADSHEETID',
        range: 'Bookeo Data!A3:K',
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var rows = response.values;
        if (rows.length === 0) {
            console.log('No data found.');
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { //problem starts here.
                (function (i) {
                    var row = rows[i];
                    //User-defined
                    //Need to for loop all these variables with callback func
                    var productId = row[1];
                    var startTime = row[2]; //31day range, ISO format
                    var endTime = row[3];
                    var fName = row[4];
                    var nAdult = row[5];
                    var nChild = row[6];
                    var phoneNum = row[7];
                    var bookNumEmail = row[8];
                    var reseller = row[9]; //hardcoded to GYG
                    //Callback function due to request being asynchronous.
                    function getAvail(callback) {
                        Request.get('https://api.bookeo.com/v2/availability/slots?productId=' + productId + '&startTime=' + startTime + '&endTime=' + endTime + '&secretKey=' + secretKey + '&type=fixed&apiKey=' + apiKey,
                            function (error, response, body) {
                                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                    const data = JSON.parse(body);
                                    var result = data["data"][0]["eventId"];
                                    console.log('Working callback!');
                                    return callback(false, result);
                                } else {
                                    return callback(error, null);
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }

                    //GET available slots & POST after recieving body from GET
                    getAvail(function (err, data) {
                        if (!err) {
                            Request.post({
                                url: 'https://api.bookeo.com/v2/bookings?startTime=' + startTime + '&endTime=' + endTime + '&secretKey=' + secretKey + '&type=fixed&apiKey=' + apiKey,
                                json: {
                                    "eventId": data,
                                    "customer": {
                                        "firstName": fName,
                                        "lastName": bookNumEmail,
                                        "phoneNumbers": [
                                            {
                                                "number": phoneNum,
                                                "type": "mobile"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "customFields": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "Reseller",
                                                "value": "GetYourGuide" //Only works when hardcoded, cannot read spreadsheet reseller
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "participants": {
                                        "numbers": [
                                            {
                                                "peopleCategoryId": "Cadults",
                                                "number": nAdult
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "peopleCategoryId": "Cchildren",
                                                "number": nChild
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "productId": productId
                                },
                            },
                                function (error, response, body) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        throw error;
                                    }
                                    console.log('Working!');
                                });
                        }
                    }); //end func
                })(i);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you make a batch request in the for loop instead of a lot of individual calls?

Comment: @Legman That's an interesting concept that I didn't know it even existed, I've found batch-request module that may do the trick. Will be back to update

Comment: Sounds good and let me know, it doesnt always exist but usually when it doesnt its because the side on the other end hasnt had time to implement something like that

Comment: @Legman Actually it may not work...someone posted an issue [link](https://github.com/socialradar/batch-request/issues/11) and this is something I am having trouble researching/figuring out as well.

Comment: So i have worked around solutions like this before, its not great.  What might be throwing it off is your call back, so when the first request gets back, if your not done making calls it could cancel the rest of your program.  You should try either waiting for the last return or making it so that the rest of the call happens outside of the callback.  Not great but that might help